# Google signIn not working with firebase Android on 6.0.1 on nexus 5

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-authentication

Google signIn not working with firebase Android on 6.0.1 on nexus 5.

Using firebase auth, signing in with Google, results failure everytime.

Anyone having the same issue please confirm or suggest solution.

Thanks

Comment: Please be specific.

Comment: What failure exception do you get? It should be returned from signIn function

Comment: Problem solved, sha1 wasn't added in the project settings at console.

Answer (score -1):

I had this same problem a few minutes ago, and solved it by updating Google Play Services in the phone from 8.0 to 11.0.